# LiveData vs Handler and LocalBroadcast

Tags: java, android

I have old Android/java code, that contains two derives from `IntentService`,
and these services **not** run in separate processes.

The question is about the way to return result from these `IntentService`.

One service return result by using `Handler` + `Runnable`, to run code in main loop:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyApplication.get().setFoo(someThing);
    }
});
```

the other one is uses `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);` to send message to `Activity`, and `Activity` subscribe via `BroadcastReceiver` on message in `onResume`, and unsubscribe in `onPause`.

Am I right, and in both case it is possible to use `LiveData` to simplify things?

`IntentService` should create `LiveData` and who want result should `observe` it,
and when new data arrives `IntentService` should call `postValue`,
or may be there are some reefs to prevent usage of `LiveData` here?

Comment: did you checked this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204978/how-to-update-livedata-of-a-viewmodel-from-background-service-and-update-ui

Comment: yes you can do this

Comment: Use ResultReceiver for Activity to IntentService communication, you can exchange the data between these components. It is useful for alternative solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `LiveData` will not help you in sending any data from `Service` to other components.

The problem with communication from any `Service` to other components is that you don't usually obtain a direct reference to the `Service`, therefore you can't directly "subscribe" to notifications.

Theoretically, if the `Service` runs in the same process, you can bind it, obtain a reference to `Service` object and then directly perform subscription. However, this is often an overkill and I don't see this pattern being used widely.

In your examples, there are two communication mechanisms:

1. Service reaches statically to Application object and sets some data. This is a communication through global state, and is generally considered an anti-pattern.
2. Communication through LocalBroadcastManager

From the above two mechanisms, I would use only #2 and avoid #1 at all costs.

Back to `LiveData`.

In order to be able to get `LiveData` object from the `Service` you will need to have a reference to that `Service`. This is usually impossible unless you bind `Service` in the same process, or use some ugly hack that involves global state.

Therefore, usefulness of `LiveData` in this context is very limited.

By the way, while LocalBroadcastManager is alright, I find this mechanism too complicated and restricting. Therefore, if the `Service` runs in the same process, I prefer to use `EventBus` in order to communicate from `Service` to other components (or vice-versa).

An example of such a communication you can see in [SQLite benchmarking application](https://github.com/techyourchance/android_sqlite_benchmark/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techyourchance/sqlitebenchmark/test/TestService.java) that I wrote several days ago. In this app, `TestService` posts status changes and test results to `EventBus` as sticky events, and `TestActivity` subscribes to those events.

Comment: Google just deprecated LocalBroadcastManager and recommends LiveData as an alternative:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/localbroadcastmanager#1.1.0-alpha01

Answer (score 2):

Both methods work with using LiveData since the purpose of LiveData is to have it on another thread and still notify users when something has changed. Seems like it would definitely replace `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);` and your IntentService would postValue. Just have your activity or anything that needs to be aware of the changes become an observer.

Comment: "Just have your activity or anything that needs to be aware of the changes become an observer" - how exactly this should be done?