# Convert LiveData to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Apparently, Room is not able to handle MutableLiveData and we have to stick to LiveData as it returns the following error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
```

I created a "custom" MutableLiveData in my DB helper this way:

```
class ProfileRepository @Inject internal constructor(private val profileDao: ProfileDao): ProfileRepo{

    override fun insertProfile(profile: Profile){
        profileDao.insertProfile(profile)
    }

    val mutableLiveData by lazy { MutableProfileLiveData() }
    override fun loadMutableProfileLiveData(): MutableLiveData<Profile> = mutableLiveData

    inner class MutableProfileLiveData: MutableLiveData<Profile>(){

        override fun postValue(value: Profile?) {
            value?.let { insertProfile(it) }
            super.postValue(value)
        }

        override fun setValue(value: Profile?) {
            value?.let { insertProfile(it) }
            super.setValue(value)
        }

        override fun getValue(): Profile? {
            return profileDao.loadProfileLiveData().getValue()
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I get the updates from DB and can save the `Profile` object but I cannot modify attributes.

For example:
`mutableLiveData.value = Profile()` would work.
`mutableLiveData.value.userName = "name"` would call `getValue()` instead `postValue()` and wouldn't work.

Did anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call me crazy but AFAIK there is zero reason to use a MutableLiveData for the object that you received from the DAO.

The idea is that you can expose an object via `LiveData<List<T>>`

```
@Dao
public interface ProfileDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PROFILE")
    LiveData<List<Profile>> getProfiles();
}
```

Now you can observe them:

```
profilesLiveData.observe(this, (profiles) -> {
    if(profiles == null) return;

    // you now have access to profiles, can even save them to the side and stuff
    this.profiles = profiles;
});
```

So if you want to make this live data "emit a new data and modify it", then you need to insert the profile into the database. The write will re-evaluate this query and it will be emitted once the new profile value is written to db.

```
dao.insert(profile); // this will make LiveData emit again
```

So there is no reason to use `getValue`/`setValue`, just write to your db.

Comment: I understand your point. The solution as it is right now doesn't differ from having a LiveData object and saving in DB. The idea here is to be able to modify independently some attributes in the database.

Comment: What happens when you've modified the objects independently from the database, and then the object is fetched from network, saved to DB, and now you have a "new state from network" and an object that is locally modified?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce facing similar problem update to db is not reflected on live data. that is why i am trying to post to mutable live data object

Comment: If you insert into DB through DAO, then if `LiveData<List<T>>` is exposed from DAO and you observe it, then you *will* receive the new data.

Answer (score 11):

If you really need to, then you can use the mediator trick.

**In your ViewModel**

```
 val sourceProduct: LiveData<Product>() = repository.productFromDao()
 val product = MutableLiveData<Product>()
    
 val mediator = MediatorLiveData<Unit>()

 init {
      mediator.addSource(sourceProduct, { product.value = it })
 }
```

**In fragment/activity**

```
observe(mediator, {})
observe(product, { /* handle product */ })
```

Comment: using this technique, any changes to the source product will automatically be triggered in the mediator livedata ? therefore I only need to observe the product or do i need to observe both the product and the mediator live data ?

Comment: @Kolaaa thats correct - you only need to observe mediator livedata

Answer (score 5):

A Kotlin extension to trasform `LiveData` into `MutableLiveData`:

```
/**
 * Transforms a [LiveData] into [MutableLiveData]
 *
 * @param T type
 * @return [MutableLiveData] emitting the same values
 */
fun <T> LiveData<T>.toMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<T> {
    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<T>()
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(this) {
        mediatorLiveData.value = it
    }
    return mediatorLiveData
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Room doesn't support `MutableLiveData` and has support for `LiveData` only, your approach of creating a wrapper is the best approach I can think of. It will be complicated for `Google` to support `MutableLiveData`since the `setValue` and `postValue` methods are `public`. Where as for `LiveData` they are `protected` which gives more control.

Answer (score -2):

In your repository you can get `LiveData` and transform it to `MutableLivedata`:

```
var data= dao.getAsLiveData()
return MutableLiveData<T>(data.value)
```

Comment: This is the wrong way, no one guarantees that there is data in livedata at the moment.

Comment: what if we check for null before?